# ASP.net and JQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

Given:

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text" />
```

Where the id = datepicker tells the javascript to attach all the datepicker code to the form element, how do I turn this into a server control?

For example:

```
<input runat="server" id="datepicker" type="text" />
```

Doesn't work because ASP.net generates it's own ID's.

**Edit**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dateTo" class="datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
```

Renders as

```
<input name="ctl00$mainContent$dateTo" type="text" id="ctl00_mainContent_dateTo" class="datepicker" />
```

And doesn't work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's a good practice to have a class which triggers a date picker to be created for everything that has it, such as 'js-date-picker'

then to avoid duplication of code, you can just write the following JS once:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".js-date-picker").datepicker();
});
```

to get ASP.net to set a class on the textbox correctly so it uses this class, just add CssClass="js-date-picker" to the tag:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dateTo" CssClass="js-date-picker" />
```

Hope this clarifies things for you.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea to bind a datepicker to an ID. better is to give it to the class (in asp.net: CssClass) 
then, multiple inputs can have datepickers. so in short, bind the datepicker to a class. This also fixes your asp.net problem about the ID's

```
<input id="aspid" class="datepicker" type="text" />

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dateTo" CssClass="datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
```

then in your jquery selector:

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker()
```

Comment: Setting class="datepicker" doesn't seem to work with jquery-ui

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the client ID of the control in the Jquery datepicker initialisation, like such:

```
$(function() {
    $("#<%=dateTo.ClientID %>").datepicker();
});
```

Seems to work :)

Comment: but it aint very extendable now is it... if you place the jquery binding code in your masterpage, then, to make a datepicker, the only thing you need to do is add the CssClass to your input and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Simple!! Use `clientidmode="static"` in your input text control.

Example- `input runat="server" id="datepicker" type="text" clientidmode="Static"`

This should solve your problem.